# I want a divorce! What's the most painless way of obtaining one?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Seriously, it was fun and all, but I can't and I don't want to stay married to the same woman for the rest of my life - one real life marriage is enough..

Is there a lawyer or process of some kind in the world of Skyrim, and if not, who could help me divorce her?

If all else should fail, *(sigh)*, do I have to take her to the backyard, thwack her head with the shovel and dig a shallow grave?

Comment: Well, you could take her on nice picking in mountains and FUS RO DAH her... If anyone aks, just say you were singing to her in Dragon language. S*it happens!

Comment: I think you need to earn the respect of The Dark Brotherhood, and then hire them for some form of mercy killing.

Comment: I've got a friend who accidentally killed his first wife...he hid the body in one of the rooms of his house. Whenever his next wife looks into the room, he kills her too to 'remove the witnesses'. He's on his 6th wife, I believe.

Comment: +1 For the title, @TheCommunistDuck, If we didn't know the context, that would sound a little... weird

Comment: @TheCommunistDuck: You're friends with Bluebeard?

Comment: I assume you are still talking about the game in the last paragraph, and not your real life marriage?

Comment: @Doomsknight Which one of my 'unsuccessful' marriages are you  referring to?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [UESP wiki, "**Skyrim - Marriage**" article](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage#Notes):

Steps to re-marry / divorce using [console commands](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) (PC only):

- Select spouse.
- Enter the following console commands:
- `removefac 51596`
- `player.removefac C6472`
- `resetquest 74793`
- `resetquest 21382`
- `setstage 74793 10`
- Wait for 24 hours.
- Then proceed to marry as normal.

---

From [TES Wiki, "**Marriage - Divorce (PC)**" article:](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Marriage#Divorce_.28PC.29)

Trying to breakup with partners is, for some reason, impossible without the console. Searching for help "breakup" 4 will bring up dialogue and quests that show reference to what must have been the original intention of breaking up with a spouse.

#### Option one

The relationshipbreakup quest can be used. Use the console to enter these commands:

- `completequest 0007431B`
- `resetquest 0007431B`
- `resetquest 00021382`

(This is just formality to reset the "marriage" quest.) The above will prevent the player from having to kill his spouse, although they will comment on how much even the thought of him makes their blood boil. Untested, but possibly `setrelationshiprank player 4` can fix this

#### Option two

- The spouse must be killed
- The console command `Setstage RelationshipMarriage 10` must then be used
- The console commands `resurrect` should next be used on the ex-spouse (and eventually the command `setrelationshiprank player 4` on him/her to keep the relationship status obtained with the NPC related quests)
- The old Amulet of Mara doesn't need to be dropped or sold.

#### Option three

- The Amulet of Mara necklace must be retained, or another one must be found.
- Any wanted items should be taken from the current spouse before starting this process.
- The following commands must be used, after targeting the spouse:

  - `removefac 51596`
  - `player.removefac C6472`
  - `resetquest 74793`
  - `resetquest 21382`
  - `setstage 74793 10`
- The old spouse will immediately exit the house and return to their regular location.
- 24 hours must be waited.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an `additem f -X` where X is half your gold?

Answer (score 10):

I'm afraid that it's off with her head, mate.

It's that, a console hack or a mod (not sure if one exists though).

Comment: It worked for Henry VIII!

Comment: A console hack...or a regular hack!

Comment: Have you done [Boethiah's Calling](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Boethiah's_Calling)? It requires that you sacrifice a named follower NPC. If your spouse is a follower, you can use them.

Answer (score 10):

Rather than posting the whole [**wiki summary on this subject**](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Marriage#Divorce), I will just link you there with a summary.

You cannot divorce without a console command

```
completequest 0007431B
resetquest 0007431B
resetquest 00021382
```

or killing.

However.

> A bug can occur if you kill your spouse. Even if you continue to wear
>   the Amulet of Mara, you may not be able to marry again.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, but I dislike using hacks

Comment: Can't blame ya there, just supplying the facts :)

Comment: Doesn't killing technically count as a divorce?

Comment: Until death do we part. It may not be a divorce. buts it is technically the end of the marriage.

Answer (score 5):

You can divorce. If she's a follower, take her to a secluded area. If she's not, you have to do this in your own house. Become a werewolf kill her and eat her body. If there's any witnesses, kill them and eat their bodies too. The game will make you mourn for a while depending on how long you were married, but eventually you will be able to remarry provided the body is gone and you get away with the murder.

Comment: Now THAT is what I call "aggressive negotiations"..

Comment: @DrFish +1 for the Star Wars reference there...