# How do I unadopt my children? (preferably without killing them)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I changed my mind and would like to adopt other kids. I would like to do this without killing my children (I'm not *that* evil) or using the 'disable' console command on them permanently (removing them from the game), kind of like the solutions for [obtaining a divorce without killing your spouse](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/41636/4797), so you could remarry.

I'm playing on the PC and would welcome solutions that are mods, console commands or save game editing *and* that won't have children killed or disabled (removed from the game). Preferably, they would still be alive and be back in their previous homes (or the streets) after the un-adoption.

*Research info*: I've [searched](https://www.google.com/search?q=skyrim+unadopt&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&q=skyrim+unadopt+OR+un-adopt&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial) and these are some of the forum posts I found where the same question is asked - but they contain no solutions. Some of the replies mention killing the children or using the 'disable' console command, but this won't actually 'unadopt' the children.

- http://steamcommunity.com/app/72850/discussions/0/828924672602440932/
- http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/936707-hearthfire-a-console-command-or-way-to-unadopt-children/
- http://www.loverslab.com/topic/18451-is-there-a-waymod-to-unadopt/
- http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:243386
- http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Child#Un-Adoption.3F

Answer (score 6):

There is a Mod called [Skyrim Unadoption Mod](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/47259/).

I haven’t tried it yet.

Comment: It's a shout to reset children to the part before adoption. They'll disappear.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways to unadopt children.

## Unadoption Mod

[Download here](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/47259/?)

> If, like me, as soon as you installed Hearthfires you went to the Orphanage and adopted two children, before realizing that there was a poor homeless girl trying to sell flowers under the snow storms of Windhelm just waiting for you to adopt her, or if you simply want to get rid of you children, then this mod is for you.
>
> The mod gives you a power (that works like a shout) that will send back your children where they came from and you will be able to adopt new ones.
>
> WARNINGS:
>   - While this mod is active, do not try to adopt more than two children.
>   - After unadopting your children, there's a small chance you might not be able to re-adopt them. So if you're thinking of re-adopting, make sure to save your game before unadopting and then you can save again only once the re-adoption worked.
>   Here's a fix if re-adopting doesn't work. It does not seem to work every time but it's quick and worth trying:
>   Open the console, click on the child, and enter "addfac XX04290 1", replacing "XX" by the load order number of your Hearthfires.esm (for instance 03 if Hearthfires is third in the load order).

The mod gives you a type of power to reset children's als to before they're adopted. According to the warning, you can only do this once since you can't readopt [bugged out, so don't worry].

## Start the DLC all over again

By uninstalling, and reinstalling the DLC, all of the thing in the DLC should reset [yes, everything! Even those 3 land plots and manors too!]. You should be able to adopt the right children and make them move to your home.

Comment: RDO, a mod that's meant to overhaul dialogue, works well for making them re-adoptable. After using the unadoption mod, go to where you found your children. Put the cursor on them and open up RDO (believe you need an ingame mod manager), select "Character options" and click "Make potential follower". Then exit out and try to talk to them. Worked immediately for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can deactivate the Hearthfire DLC from Data Files in the Skyrim start up.

This will reset the whole Hearthfire DLC, leaving the children's bedroom un-renovated and both of your kids un-adopted. Then you can start the whole thing all over again.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it. I did that and I forgot about the 2 houses I had already built. All that work down the drain? Just think about it before you restart hearthfire.