# Can I re-marry?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

Can you re-marry if your spouse is killed in battle? I tried wearing the Amulet of Mara again while around the house-carl Gregor from Dawnstar. So far it did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: As far as I am aware, you're out of luck and doomed to loneliness :(

Answer (score 5):

If you're playing on the PC, you should be able to remarry by using the console:

- Make a backup save
- Select your spouse (either by entering `prid <spouse's refID>`  in the console or by clicking on your spouse's corpse with the console opened)
- Enter the following console commands:
- `removefac 51596`
- `player.removefac C6472`
- `resetquest 74793`
- `resetquest 21382`
- `setstage 74793 10`
- Wait for 24 hours.
- Proceed to marry as normal.

<sup>Source: [UESP wiki, "**Skyrim - Marriage**" article](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage#Notes)</sup>
If the above fails, load the backup save and try [other methods of remarrying](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/116495/4797).

Answer (score 0):

No, I am afraid not. At least not without using console commands. You can't revive your spouse either (trough console)... Well, you can, but once revived they will not act as your spouse, just whatever the regular NPC they were before marriage.

While on it, it seems you can't end a marriage either. The only thing you can do is "leave them at the altar". It seems, that once married, you will forever be marked as such, even upon death of spouse.

Comment: What "console commands" are those?

Comment: I sadly do not know the specific ones, but I am certain you will likely find it here (with possible other commands you might find handy for "tricky" situations): http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_(Skyrim)

Answer (score 0):

There should be a speech option next time you talk to them. You can marry again if your spouse has died, in fact it is the only way to remarry on *console*. I married and accidently killed both Lydia and Uthgerd the Unbroken before I married Ysolda.