# So my wife was killed, now what?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Long story short I married Lydia, she died in battle, and I resurrected her through console commands.  Now speaking with her doesn't have the usual spouse dialogue, I also am not able to get normal marriage interest dialogue with other marriageable NPCs. Any idea what is up and how I can fix this?

Comment: What console commands did you use to resurrect her?

Comment: @galacticninja It is not the command that makes her AI malfunction, it is a property within a game, whenever you resurrect any NPC, their AI is reset.

Answer (score 16):

The best thing you can do is remarry her. There is no known fix as far as I know. It was never intended to revive NPCs, so there is no fallback to such situations.

How to divorce is already explained in [this thread](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41636/i-want-a-divorce-whats-the-most-painless-way-of-obtaining-one).

Answer (score 7):

Since you can access console by ~ key, just type the following commands to make her your wife again:

1. Click on Lydia
2. addfac 19809 1

And you are done! She is your wife again.

If this does not work out, try to write these commands first:

**Setrelationshiprank "NPC ID HERE" 4**

**Player.setrelationshiprank "NPC ID HERE" 4**

**Disable**

**Enable**

And then do the above command again. The cool part is that you can use it in any NPC. So yeah, your problem does have a solution.

This basically happens as when you revive any NPC, the AI is reset, along with the faction status as well. 
For eg- if your follower ever died, and you revived them, you will need to ask then to follow you again.

You can get the NPC ID via the wiki, or by using Skyrim help!

Answer (score 5):

When you revive a NPC in console, the system still believes you are married, but not to the Revived Lydia.

Comment: Do you also know how to fix it? I think Jdecker already understood this, but wants to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the revived Lydia is not Lydia, it's a clone so its a totally different character then. If you want to fix this try reloading a save or try the console commands. Your best chance is to try the console as I doubt you will have the save.

Answer (score 0):

For a slightly more canonical way of fixing your dilemma you could simply reset the marriage quest. Go to the console and type `resetquest RelationshipMarriage` then exit the console, drop your Amulet of Mara (preferably somewhere you can find it again) and go visit the Temple of Mara monk in Riften as you did to originally start the quest.