# Skyrim Wedding Issue

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I was playing anytime and wanted to get married, I had everything set up and when I go to the Church everybody says Congratulations on your wedding, but Maramal is apparently busy and I haven't even attended the wedding, now I am so far in the game and want to go back.

What do I do now?

Comment: Hi Nick. Your question is really vague: can you please expand a little bit? What were the steps you took to get married? When was Maramal busy? How did you find out you didn't attend your wedding? If this problem occurred way back during your playthrough, it probably can't be fixed. If you really want to go back, you can load an old save. You can try [divorcing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41636/i-want-a-divorce-whats-the-most-painless-way-of-obtaining-one) Maramal, *if* according to the game you are married.